# How to identify the Maximum fluctuations in time series data in R?

Tags: r

I have time series data for a particular period of time.For example:

```
Time                           Volume
2012-10-01 10:30:01             4567
2012-10-01 10:30:02             1235
2012-10-01 10:30:03             3645
..........   .....              .....



2012-10-01 10:30:49              4646894
```

I want to identify the maximum fluctuation in the given time series data is at: 2012-10-01  10:30:49. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: By maximum fluctuation do you just mean the point at which "Volume" is at a maximum?

Comment: perhaps `min()` or `max()` or `which.min()` or `which.max()`

Comment: @Dason Yes It should be identify that at what time the volume is maximum or maximum fluctuated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm interpreting "maximum fluctuated" to mean change. If that is incorrect, please let me know. 
Below are a few different optinos. *`tsDat` would be the name of your `data.frame`*

```
# Greatest increase in volume
diffs <- c(0, diff(tsDat$Volume))
tsDat[diffs == max(diffs), ]

# Greatest absolute increase in volume
diffs <- c(0, abs(diff(tsDat$Volume)))
tsDat[diffs == max(diffs), ]

# Greatest volumne
tsDat[tsDat$Volume==max(tsDat$Volume), ]
```

---

Using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
myDT <- data.table(tsDat, key="Volume")

myDT[.(max(Volume)), Time]
```